# Update trigger in SQL needs cleaning up

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the format for some of the Update triggers on a website I'm working on. In fact, the Insert and Delete use a similar format as below (the repetitive nature). This seems like a lot of repetition. Is there a way I can clean this up without having to do an individual insert on each field into my Audit table (as demonstrated below)?

```
USE [DatabaseName]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[update_iep_serv] 
ON  [dbo].[iep_serv] 
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @iepservpk [int]
DECLARE @iepfk [int]
DECLARE @arcfk[int]
DECLARE @start [date]
DECLARE @term [date] 
DECLARE @thr_code [char] (3)
DECLARE @thr_type [char] (3)
DECLARE @cotreat[char] (2)
DECLARE @frequency [smallint]
DECLARE @duration [numeric] (4,2)
DECLARE @period [char] (2)
DECLARE @therapist [int] 
DECLARE @empfk [int]
DECLARE @tablelock [varchar] (50)

DECLARE @iepservpk_n [int]
DECLARE @iepfk_n [int]
DECLARE @arcfk_n [int]
DECLARE @start_n [date]
DECLARE @term_n [date] 
DECLARE @thr_code_n [char] (3)
DECLARE @thr_type_n [char] (3)
DECLARE @cotreat_n[char] (2)
DECLARE @frequency_n [smallint]
DECLARE @duration_n [numeric] (4,2)
DECLARE @period_n [char] (2)
DECLARE @therapist_n [int] 
DECLARE @empfk_n [int]
DECLARE @tablelock_n [varchar] (50)

 select 
 @iepservpk=iepservpk,
 @iepfk = iepfk, 
 @arcfk = arcfk,
 @start = start,
 @term=term,
 @thr_code=thr_code,
 @thr_type =thr_type,
 @cotreat=cotreat,
 @frequency=frequency, 
 @duration=duration,
 @period = period,
 @therapist = therapist,
 @empfk = empfk,
 @tablelock = tablelock
 from deleted

 select 
 @iepservpk_n=iepservpk,
 @iepfk_n = iepfk, 
 @arcfk_n = arcfk,
 @start_n = start,
 @term_n=term,
 @thr_code_n=thr_code,
 @thr_type_n =thr_type,
 @cotreat_n=cotreat,
 @frequency_n=frequency, 
 @duration_n=duration,
 @period_n = period,
 @therapist_n = therapist,
 @empfk_n = empfk,
 @tablelock_n= tablelock
 from inserted 


-- Insert statements for trigger here

IF @iepservpk != @iepservpk_n OR (@iepservpk is null AND @iepservpk_n is not null) OR (@iepservpk is not null AND @iepservpk_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'iepservpk',@iepservpk,@iepservpk_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END


IF @iepfk != @iepfk_n OR (@iepfk is null AND @iepfk_n is not null) OR (@iepfk is not null AND @iepfk_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'iepfk',@iepfk,@iepfk_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @arcfk != @arcfk_n OR (@arcfk is null AND @arcfk_n is not null) OR (@arcfk is not null AND @arcfk_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'arcfk',@arcfk,@arcfk_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @start != @start_n OR (@start is null AND @start_n is not null) OR (@start is not null AND @start_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'start',@start,@start_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @term != @term_n OR (@term is null AND @term_n is not null) OR (@term is not null AND @term_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'term',@term,@term_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @thr_code != @thr_code_n OR (@thr_code is null AND @thr_code_n is not null) OR (@thr_code is not null AND @thr_code_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'thr_code',@thr_code,@thr_code_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @thr_type != @thr_type_n OR (@thr_type is null AND @thr_type_n is not null) OR (@thr_type is not null AND @thr_type_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'thr_type',@thr_type,@thr_type_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @cotreat != @cotreat_n OR (@thr_type is null AND @cotreat_n is not null) OR (@cotreat is not null AND @cotreat_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'cotreat',@cotreat,@cotreat_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @frequency != @frequency_n OR (@frequency is null AND @frequency_n is not null) OR (@frequency is not null AND @frequency_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'frequency',@frequency,@frequency_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @duration != @duration_n OR (@duration is null AND @duration_n is not null) OR (@duration is not null AND @duration_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'duration',@duration,@duration_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @period != @period_n OR (@period is null AND @period_n is not null) OR (@period is not null AND @period_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'period',@period,@period_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @therapist != @therapist_n OR (@therapist is null AND @therapist_n is not null) OR (@therapist is not null AND @therapist_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'therapist',@therapist,@therapist_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @empfk != @empfk_n OR (@empfk is null AND @empfk_n is not null) OR (@empfk is not null AND @empfk_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'empfk',@empfk,@empfk_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END

IF @tablelock != @tablelock_n OR (@tablelock is null AND @tablelock_n is not null) OR (@tablelock is not null AND @tablelock_n is null)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Audit].[dbo].[AUDITACT]
       ([databaseName]
       ,[tableName]
       ,[tablefk]
       ,[fieldname]
       ,[old]
       ,[new]
       ,[userfk]
       ,[username]
       ,[action]
       ,[entrytime])
    VALUES
        ('Support','IEP_SERV',@iepservpk,'tablelock',@tablelock,@tablelock_n,@empfk,@tablelock_n,'UPDATE',GETDATE())
END
END
```

Comment: This is a terrible trigger on so many levels.  The "SELECT" statements from inserted and deleted are wrong to start with, because the inserted and deleted collections can and will contain multiple rows... these assume just one row.  So they'll do the wrong thing any time there's a multi-row insert, update, or delete (the latter two are VERY common).  This is completely awful.

Comment: Use JOINs to `inserted` and `deleted` instead of variables.   Use CASE expressions to set the "hard-coded" values (`fieldname`), instead of multiple queries in IF blocks.

Comment: @pmbAustin Not sure if you downvoted this but this is what I walked into. Trying to fix it. EVERY trigger is like this and believe me, there are a ton. I feel sorry for the person who set them up. I suspected these were just bad.

Comment: @TabAlleman Mind putting up an example as an answer? This seems like a logical and efficient approach.

Comment: I did not downvote, no. I wouldn't do that.  But Tab Alleman is correct... the trigger needs a complete rewrite. Dump all the variables.  Join to the Inserted and Deleted tables and in an INSERT INTO x FROM (SELECT the values FROM inserted blah blah blah) in order to determine what to do.  It won't be simple, but it'll work and it'll be efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Mm, it's not as simple as I thought because you would need to do multiple inserts if multiple conditions are true.   So you still need multiple inserts (instead of CASE statements), but you can do the inserts with JOINs instead of variables and IF blocks:

```
--This inserts all the rows where ColumnNameA was updated
INSERT INTO AuditTable (Col1, Col2, FieldNameCol)
SELECT Col1, Col2, 'ColumnNameA'
FROM Inserted i
INNER JOIN Deleted d
  ON i.ColumnNameA<>d.ColumnNameA

--Then repeat the above for each other ColumnName you want to check
```

Comment: I would like to add we don't do multiple inserts at once. It's a single entry form (all of our pages are, in fact). Does that change this at all? Sounds like it could simplify it like you originally thought.

Comment: Well, your existing logic looks to see if Field A changed, and if it did, it creates an audit row for Field A.   Then it checks to see if Field B changed, and if it did, it creates an audit row for Field B, and so on.   So in a single insert, if multiple fields changed, then you need to create multiple audit rows.   It doesn't matter that you only updated one row in the original table.   If you want to keep that logic, then you have to have multiple inserts in your trigger, like I illustrated in this answer.